# Android: How to show wifi setting in pop up window

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-activity

I have following code, which bring my app to the background and bring out the WIFI setting

```
startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS));
```

Is it possible to have the **WIFI** setting shown up in a alert dialog so it doesn't leave my app?

Thanks.

Comment: no, it is not possible, as Android does not support it. You may want to create your own UI for WIFI, where you will be able to connect and disconnect from the networks, etc. But your app will require appropriate permissions

Comment: i m leaning toward your answer =(